# Where does SQL Server 2008 store the installation logs?

Tags: sql-server-2008

This might sound like an odd question, but I just can't seem to find the installation logs of my Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express installation. According to several [Microsoft Support articles](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/955396) they are supposed to be stored in the following directory, yet the sub folder Setup Bootstrap does not exist for me.

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Setup Bootstrap\Log\
```

Are there any other directories where the installer saves installation logs and/or is there a way of overriding it? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you checking `C:\Program Files (x86)` in a 64-bit installation?

You should be checking  `C:\Program Files`.

Comment: Oh damnit, that's it! I was just checking the C:\Program Files\ directory but the log files were stored in C:\Program Files (x86)\. Many thanks for your answer!